# azure scale basic to standard

Tags: azure, scaling, azure-web-app-service

I have a azure basic solution, and I want to scale it to standard so then my question is will this change anything for my site already running on the basic solution. 
Im thinking if it will change ip and domain configurations, Im asking because this is a customer site and I don't want the site to go down, and I can't change the dns because the customer only have access to that.

My first impression was that nothing would happen, but was a little worried because it seems like a whole new server when I go from basic to standard and not just scaler on standard.

Comment: Is this about an Azure Website or a Cloud Service?

Comment: this is a Azure Website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get assigned an IP address with Azure Websites (aside from inbound IP if you purchase an SSL cert; outbound is still multi-tenant). It's a multi-tenant service.

Nothing needs to be changed with DNS. Traffic is just routed to your new dedicated VM instances, where your websites will now reside once you upgrade to Standard.

Answer (score 0):

When you scale up your Azure website, the ip-address will probably change, since you're moving to another virtual server (This shouldn't be a problem though). Your Domain configuration however will not change, so your client is safe.

If you really want to keep the same ip-address when scaling, you could look into [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/05/05/how-to-get-a-static-ip-address-for-your-microsoft-azure-web-site.aspx).

Comment: Azure Websites, as a service, does not offer IP addresses for each deployment (unlike cloud services). It's a multi-tenant service, with the same IP address(es) used for the entire service (aside from ones tied to SSL certs, which is mentioned in the article you linked to). Also note that inbound IP for SSL is unrelated to outbound IP address, which is shared.